# React index.html rendered but react component does not

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i couldn't figure out why ReactDOM does't render my simple component but seems to keep and render just the plain index.html

[image]

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "client2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node buildScripts/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ],
    "env": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

webpack.config.dev.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import path from 'path'

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


export default {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')  
   ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module:{
    rules:[
        {test: /\.js$/ , loader:'babel-loader', exclude: '/node_modules/'},
        {test: /\.jsx$/ , loader:'babel-loader', exclude: '/node_modules/'}
    ]
  },
  plugins:[
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body'
   })
  ] 
}
```

buildScript/server.js

```
    import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import config from '../webpack.config.dev';

const compiler = webpack(config);

/* var express = require('express')
var path = require('path') */

const port = 8081;
const app = express();

app.listen(port, function (error) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.html'));
});

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));
```

src/index.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log("App Hello")
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Howdy from React!</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

src/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hey!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only response i get is

[image]

With no logs from my index.js react "App".

I've been trying several solutions, none happened aside from my express server not working. What might be the problem here ? Thank you very much !

Comment: you need to import the js file, which you are building in webpack. You don't have anything included right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in comment, you should include your js

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hey!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have tried doing what you mentioned and now i get a 404 response - "/bundle.js" not found. any suggestions ? what am i missing ?

Comment: This is strange. Do you have bundle.js after build in your src folder?

Answer (score 1):

Your html file needs to link to `bundle.js`

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have tried doing what you mentioned and now i get a 404 response - "/bundle.js" not found. any suggestions ? what am i missing ?

Comment: Right now your server will only serve `index.html`. Maybe look at `express.static` to serve all files from your site directory.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Leo Odishvili and Ben West for helping above - the answer is really adding `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>` to the index.html

The only change was to 
change `/bundles.js` to `"./webservice_entrypoint/bundle.js"`as webservice_entrypoint would be the url path to my react app.

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check the "html-webpack-plugin" and add the plugin to the "plugins" configuration of the webpack.config.js, this will allow you to use any template html file from inside your src directly and bundle it in the dist/ folder with the included script tag already compiled and added. It is really an useful plugin.